# Don't understand solution to this mock AMC 12?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

[I don't get the answer to the solution of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcsvB.jpg)
I understand that k=c+8, but I don't understand why the upper bound of k is when x=0, as x has to be a positive real number. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $x<0$ then $x-2<-2,$ so $(x-2)^2>4.$

Comment: yes, but doesn't x have to be positive?

Comment: If there is a negative root $x,$ then $2(x-2)^2>8$ so if $k<8$ there is no negative root.  This doesn't show that there exist two positive roots when $k<8.$  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes, and it also says that x has to positive in the problem

Comment: @varunr Yes, but as $x$ gets close to to $0$, $k$ gets close to $8$.  The length of the open interval $(0,8)$ is $8$.